# Sampling a continuous time signal in a DSP

Tags: filter, signal-processing, sampling

We are tasked with sampling a continuous time signal in a DSP.

Before sampling, the signal goes through an analog filter of which I know the continuous frequency function H(ω). I also know the Fourier transform of the signal X(ω). The task is to investigate how the filtered signal is affected by the sampling rate.

My approach is to convert X(ω) to discrete time and then check how it's behaving in response. Is this the right direction? Do I also need to convert the filter to discrete time, or can I just see how Xd(ω) is related to the sampling rate and then filter it with Xd(ω)*H(ω)?

I also want to plot the output magnitude.  What is the easiest way to do this in Matlab?

Comment: get something like https://app.grammarly.com/ to check your spelling errors

Comment: You can do this in the log amplitude vs frequency domain with the sampling error, dynamic range, transfer function, spectral density and the aliasing contribution to SNR of the filter,  all  in dB

Comment: Your problem: Sampling can cause aliasing i.e. some frequency components are mixed to lower frequency. Filtering them after the aliasing has happened affects differently than filtering them in continuous time domain. Proof: Input is something with spectral content beyond the Nyquist limit. The filter is a lowpass filter which removes everything at and above the Nyquist limit. You should try to present a general rule what is the effect.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think I understand the point of the exercise now. Great explanation!